# Как программно поставить указатель в TextBox?

Tags: c#, uwp

Делаю что-то вроде анкеты, в которой необходимо заполнить все поля. Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки, если не заполнено какое либо поле, в него переместился курсор?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет ничего проще:

```
textBox1.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, найти никак не мог... А что значит код в скобочках?

Comment: @Denisok не за что. Параметр указывает, каким образом контрол получает фокус (в данном случае программно). Это значение может влиять на то, как фокус будет отображаться визуально. Подробнее можете прочитать в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/hh702161.aspx).

Comment: еще раз спасибо